# Moving Combobox value and display member to datagridview on button click

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I am currently working with vb.net, studio express 2013, with an SQL back end. I have a combobox that I am using an SQL select statement to call a value member and a display member, they are two different values. Now, I have an assortment of datagrid views in which I need to be able to add both the value member and display member to any of the datagridviews on a button click event. Each DGV has a button with a plus mark that I need to click to move the information in the combobox to  that specific DGV. Each DGV represents a different station that information will be sent to. I have attached a picture to help sort it out. [image]

ALL CODE UNDER THIS LINE IS FINAL AND CORRECT CODE!

I got it to half way work by setting up column names that were identical to the sql command to fill the combobox. here is the code:. This is done on the form load event.

```
        If DGV.Columns.Count = 0 Then
        DGV.Columns.Add("SQL ColName", "Columnheadertext")
        DGV.Columns.Add("SQLcolumn2name", "SColumn 2 header texxt")
    End If
```

By setting up the DGV on the load event I can now insert into the dgv.
I am trying to have the + button run this code"

```
 Private Sub BtnSGAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSGAdd.Click
    DGVSG.Rows.Add(CBShear.Text, CBShear.SelectedValue.ToString)
End Sub
```

However, this is literally just causing the string to be written. I need to reference the actual datatable used to load my combobox to pull these numbers.

Comment: How many columns does your GridViews have? Did you specify them design-time or run-time? Do all your grid views have the same number and name of columns?

Comment: My DGVs' have no columns set up. I am trying to set them up on run time. When the form first loads they are just blank DGVs'. I essentially need to copy the data from the combobox into the dgv. That combobox has an sql column that is made from casting certain characters in a string to make the number. I need to move both the original characters and the selected characters into the DGV.

Comment: @JoshPart I think i need to set up the DGVs' to accept the combobox data before i use the button event. Would the DGV accept the data if it had matching columns of the data im trying to pull before I try to send the data?

Comment: Ok, reading your comment here and the exception thrown. I'm pretty sure the problem is that, to add a row to a `DataGridView`, you need first to specify it's columns. I'll put an answer addresing that.

Comment: @JoshPart I got half of it to work by setting up my column in the load event, however, Now I am only getting one part of the column, is there any way to pull the other part? .......In an easier to tell way, My combobox is bound to a datatable that has been filled with an sql command. I am currently pulling one half of that 2 column datatable, the number in the combobox. Is there a way to reference that Datatable and pull the other part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the columns of the `DataGridView` first before you add rows to it.

Try something like this:

```
If DGV.Columns.Count = 0 then
    DGV.Columns.Add("Column1_Name", "Column1_Header")
    DGV.Columns.Add("Column2_Name", "Column2_Header")
End If

DGV.Rows.Add(ComboBox1.Text, ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString)
```

This assuming that your ComboBox is Data-Bounded and it has the `ValueMember` and the `DisplayMember` assigned.

Comment: I do have those members assigned, let me try this code.

Comment: I set up the columns this way and it seems to work. However now i need to handle my button click event. here is the code: check my original post for the code. When i use DGV.Rows.Add({"Col_1", "Col_2"}), i am literraly just writing the column names into the table. It is not referencing the original sql datatable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you simply just need to add a row to your datagridview in the event handler of the corresponding + button

```
dgv.Rows.Add(YourComboBox.Text)
```

If you have multiple columns that you need to fill, then use an array.

```
dgv.Rows.Add({"first column data", "second column data", "etc."})
```

Comment: Not meaning to be mean... but you can't expect code to work just copying-pasting it. You need to *adapt* it to your program and needs.

Comment: I did adapt it, but this is company code and i can not give out our internal column names and such. I obviously used the proper column names and design names for my objects on the forms. its just to protect my company to use generic things like "dgv" and "combobox."

Comment: I think the problem here is coming from the fact that the combobox box is sql bound data. I might need to set up my columns some hows to make it work.

Comment: I'll take back my previous comment then, and suggest you to edit your post to say why it didn't work or what error/exception your attempt threw.

Comment: ahh yes of course, here is the error code.   "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll"